# transpose groups of obs appearing more than once

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this one

```
familyid Year  memberid count var
1        2000  1        2     5
1        2000  1        2     6
1        2000  2        1     8
2        2000  1        1     5
2        2000  2        1     4
3        2000  1        1     5
3        2000  2        2     7
3        2000  2        2     5
```

where the column count indicates how many times each observation compares in the dataframe. I want to transpose the dataframe only for those comparing more than one times, in other words I want to have

```
familyid     Year  memberid count var_1  var_2
    1        2000  1        2     5      6
    1        2000  2        1     8      NA
    2        2000  1        1     5      NA
    2        2000  2        1     4      NA
    3        2000  1        1     5      NA
    3        2000  2        2     7      5
```

What do you suggest to use for this purpose?
Thank you so much.

Comment: `library(data.table);setDT(df1)[,newID := paste0("var_",1:.N), by = .(familyid, Year, memberid, count)];dcast(df1, familyid + Year + memberid + count ~ newID, value.var = "var")`

Comment: Thank you Andre, this works perfectly. I was missing the first step! Solved.